# How does pull work with git?

Tags: git

I have a question regarding git repository management.

Lets say I want to create a new branch from 'develop' for a patch.  Easy enough:

```
sudo git checkout develop && sudo git checkout -b test-patch
```

I also want collaboration, so I am going to push that branch to our remote:

```
sudo git push -u origin test-patch
```

Now, I want to pull in changes because another developer has finished a piece of the patch:

```
sudo git pull origin test-patch
```

So, here is my question...

**EDIT**

Now that I understand that origin refers to the repository that the branch hails from,
does `sudo git pull origin test-patch` get any changes from the remote copy of the 'test-patch' branch and apply those changes to the local copy (excluding the possibility of conflicts)?

Comment: Just curious, why do you do all of your git commands as su?

Comment: In other words, don't use `sudo` on git. There isn't really any reason you should be running those commands as root.

Comment: could you tell me how to avoid using sudo?  I get permission denied frequently

Comment: `git push origin test
fatal: unable to connect to cache daemon: Permission denied
Username for 'https://github.com': `

Comment: please don't alter your question by asking another or a new question. you can just open a new Question ;)

Comment: Sorry ;)  Won't happen again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `origin` identifies the remote from which you want to pull. When you clone a repo with git, that repo you clone from will by default be registered as a remote called `origin`.

You can change that name or add other remotes with the command [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

Comment: So when I say `sudo git pull origin test-patch`, it is pulling in changes from the 'test-patch' branch that is sitting on remote and duplicating those changes onto my local copy of the branch?